# Alternative to yahoo finance api

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I am new to yahoo finance api. I am also a beginner investor. I always use yahoo finance api to keep track of my investment portfolio. But it does not work recently due to yahoo stopping this service. Will you kindly share any alternatives for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives, but I suppose you are looking for free services? One alternative is [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/). There is a Database called "Wiki" that is free.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for free services. This is because I want to automate the process of finding 5 year low stock prices and their respective dividends in David Fish's 800+ stock lists.

Comment: It seems that the two decades of free available stock prices is coming to an end and I suppose that in mid-term, all stock data must be paid.

Comment: The "Wiki" Database has been removed in first half of 2018. But they offer some other free databases. Alternatively, you could use data from (https://www.alphavantage.co/).

Answer (score 0):

When I re-looked at this question now, I realised I have a solution for it.

I picked up python and found out about this yahoo finance library.

https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- https://www.alphavantage.co/ which is free and offers plenty of possibilities
- https://iexcloud.io/ which is also free
- https://www.quandl.com/tools/api which is also free but offers more options (for some of them you need a subscription)
- https://rapidapi.com/marketplace which offers free APIs (to get financial news, trading data, financial data,...)
- Some webscraping tools and get data directly from yahoo finance

Answer (score -2):

[AssetMacro.com API](https://www.assetmacro.com/assetmacro-api/) provides free access to historical data for 120,000+ Financial Securities (Stocks, Bonds, Commodities, Currencies, Credit Default Swaps, Indices) and Macroeconomic Variables for 120 countries.